# Is JTAG faster than SWD for debugging on an STM32F with STLINK-V3SET programmer?

Tags: stm32, st-link

There is a new [STLINK-V3SET](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stlink-v3set.html) programmer that someone dropped off on my desk today. It supports USB 2.0. My thinking is that if SWD is the bandwidth limiter in the signal chain then a new programmer isn't very useful.

Is SWD or JTAG faster with ST-link programmers and what are those speeds?

Do I get any benefit in speed from the new STLINK-V3SET programmer?

Edit:

My targets are STM32F4, STM32H7 and STM32F2

Comment: JTAG/SWD speed depends on the target, layout and luck. Working dual digit MHz boards are rare.

Comment: Can't answer because I'm using a Lauterbach debugger (which have USB 3 nowadays). The SWD speed you can reach is dependent on the clock you are running the controller with. More than a factor of 4 is hard to reach in my experience. Anything above 10 MHz seems also hard to reach (with just the wires I'm soldering to test points). Depending on how the debugger is working a reduced latency by USB 2.0 (if there is any) might actually be beneficial. For a peek breakpoint with my Lauterbach I'm not getting below 1 ms of interruption which hurts in some applications.

Comment: In general SWD is slower than JTAG (because SWD multiplexes data going in both directions on a single wire), but keep in mind that in practice the "speed" is mostly limited by flash write/erase time, not necessarily by bus clock frequency. Debugging, setting breakpoints etc. is too fast to care in both cases.

Comment: You have the hardware, why don't you try it and report back?  But consider also that usage is going to matter, something like flashing is likely not transport limited.  Semi-hosting type debugging could be, but it's not clear that JTAG would be better than something asynchronous and dedicated like SWO.  You might see the biggest gains in an automated interactive flow with the debug core that needs to move substantial data, but those needs may not be all that common...

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have a few projects that I need to get done, and I wanted someone else to have the opportunity

Comment: [Here](https://blog.st.com/stlink-v3set-in-circuit-debugger-programmer/) is an advertising blurb about their new ST-Link/V3. They claim greater speed, and a bunch of other enhancements...

Comment: Versus what? Most SWD programmers are still USB Full-Speed and not USB High-Speed. This means that their USB turnaround latency is on the order of milliseconds (although I think there can be exceptions for bulk transfers with custom drivers) --likely much slower than your SWD/JTAG interface. A USB High-Speed SWD programmer has a USB turnaround latency on the order of 10s of microseconds--which is about the same speed as an SWD transaction (roughly 40 clocks at 10MHz is 4 microseconds--and most board designs can't sustain a 10MHz SWD system reliably). However, as always, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I wonder why interface speed even comes into discussion of the _debugging_ process limited by the extremely (relative to MCU) speed of human interaction?

Comment: because the data can be slow to load if you have watched variables, and the debugger transfers more information the more watched variables you have. Speed is also useful for looking at memory.